# How do I set the value of a TextView to user input of EditText

Tags: android

here is what I have

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.subject1);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.testText);
    String value = editText.getText().toString();
    textView.setText(value);

}
```

for some reason this does not work? It just makes textView blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onCreate is when the `Activity` starts. I am sure that when this happens, you haven't typed anything with it. What you need is `TextWatcher` if you want it countinouly do this.

Answer (score 2):

first look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  String value = editText.getText().toString();
                  textView.setText(value);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a textChangeListener on your editText, and in that listener you can set the text of your textView